# Using a database connection from a different jframe

Tags: java, mysql

i got this declared in one jframe (Main)

```
 Connection con;
```

i want to use that same connection in a other jframe(Gegevens)

```
 try {
        PreparedStatement stat1 = con.prepareStatement("SELECT idrecepten , p.naam , p.achternaam , m.naam , m.fabrikant , m.dosering FROM recepten r JOIN patienten p ON r.patient = p.idpatienten JOIN medicijnen m ON r.medicijn = m.idmedicijnen WHERE r.patient = ? ");
        stat1.setString(1,primarykey[0]);
        ResultSet resultaat = stat1.executeQuery();

        while(resultaat.next())
        {
           gegevens.model2.addElement(resultaat.getString(1)+" "+ resultaat.getString(2) +" "+ resultaat.getString(3)+" "+ resultaat.getString(4) +" "+ resultaat.getString(5) +" " + resultaat.getString(6));
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
```

as you can see i am filling the model2 from the jframe(Main), but i want to fill the model in the constructor of the OTHER jframe(Gegevens), same result different approach. BUT

i want to use one only database connection so do i or do i not use the same database connect if i do this:

```
 Main main = new Main();
```

and then use the connection

```
 main.con
```

Comment: Don't think of this in terms of passing information from "one JFrame to anther" but rather as of passing information from one object to another. How do you normally do this? Usually by passing it via a constructor or method parameter, right? Well you'd do the same here.

Comment: Consider to use pooled connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is to construct your code so that when the second/other `JFrame`s are instantiated, that you pass the `Connection` object as a parameter to the constructor.

Comment: i already used static and its been told that its not safe to use static because the variable is not stored in the object but in the class it self eh?

Comment: That's true. It was bad recommendation as it's the easiest, but you/they are right. See my edits.

Comment: 'public Main(Object con) {}' if that is my constructor, is that how i do it?

Comment: public Main(Connection con) { ... } so you dont need to cast anything -- type safety.

Comment: how do i call it from the other class

Comment: If they have a reference to that the Main object (instance) then you can create a getter method to expose the connection to other classes that have a reference to your Main object.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24076/discussion-between-hamchi-and-kevin-mangold)